# Doctrine2/Symfony2 field value conversion using custom mapping types

Tags: mysql, symfony, doctrine-orm, point

I'm trying to define a custom data type for Symfony2 using Doctrine2. I've found this solution in the Doctrine documentation:

http://docs.doctrine-project.org/en/latest/cookbook/advanced-field-value-conversion-using-custom-mapping-types.html

But it doesn't work because **it keeps sending the whole Point object as a parameter for the query and not the string that the PointType should return**. I know that there's is another solution using the pack PHP function and it does work fine (I took it from here: https://github.com/jhartikainen/doctrine2-spatial/blob/master/Wantlet/ORM/PointType.php) but I'm curious about this error with the doctrine documentation solution. Anyone have seen this problem before?

Thank you very much!

Comment: What are you returning in your `convertToDatabaseValue()` method?

Comment: It should return a string like this one after calling convertToDatabaseValue and convertToDatabaseValueSQL:
PointFromText('POINT(lat lng)')
But the query that Doctrine is trying to make gets an object as argument instead of the string. With the other solution, that is quite similar to this one but doesn't use the convertToDatabaseValueSQL, everything works fine, the query gets a string. This is the code from convertToDatabaseValue:
if ($value instanceof Point) {
            $value = sprintf('POINT(%F %F)', $value->getLongitude(), $value->getLatitude());
        }
        return $value;

Comment: And this is the code from ConvertToDatabaseValueSQL:
`return sprintf('PointFromText(%s)', $sqlExpr);`